# Where is Observable#asObservable() in RxJava2?

Tags: java, reactivex

I would like to observe my `BehaviourSubject`. In RxJava 1 I was calling [asObservable()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#asObservable()), which is now gone.

I found [`publish()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#publish()) but it returns connectable, which I don't want to.

How to turn behavior subject into observable in RxJava 2?

Answer (score 18):

From the [What's different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#operator-differences) page, from 1.x Observable to 2.x Flowable :

> asObservable :    renamed to hide(), hides all identities now

So it seems that the [hide](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#hide()) method is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12):

You're probably looking for [`Observable.hide()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#hide())

> Hides the identity of this Observable and its Disposable. Allows
>   hiding extra features such as Subject's Observer methods or preventing
>   certain identity-based optimizations (fusion).